# Apache VirtualHost configuration won't get matched

Tags: apache-2.4

I have the following configuration, with Varnish acting as a cache between the externally facing endpoint (NGINX) and Apache.

```
+-------+        +-------+       +------+
| NGINX |  +---> |Varnish| +---> |Apache|
+-------+        +-------+       +------+
```

I can't get my Apache VirtualHost configuration to match, when I call it from a browser. The configuration for my (single) VirtualHost looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName fabrikam.com
    ServerAlias fabrikam.com
    ServerAdmin myemailaddress
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-mycustomlog.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's the Apache version:

```
root@localhost:/etc/apache2# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jan 14 2016 17:45:23
```

## Symptom

When I access `https://fabrikam.com`, it doesn't give me the root of the `/var/www/html` folder. Instead, it tries to access the root of `/var/www`, and because I disabled `mod_index`, it gives me a HTTP 404 Not Found error.

Any thoughts on how to get this VirtualHost configuration to "match" properly? When I access fabrikam.com, it should go to the `/var/www/html` folder, instead of `/var/www` in the `apache2.conf` file.

EDIT

Here's the output from `apachectl -S`

```
root@localhost:/etc/apache2# apachectl -S                                       
VirtualHost configuration:                                                                       
*:80                   fabrikam.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)   
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"                                                                    
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"                                                        
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"                                      
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl               
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults                                                       
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults                                            
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"                                             
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS                                                                            
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG                                                                         
User: name="www-data" id=33                                                              
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

## NGINX Configuration

```
### Rewrite non-HTTPS URLs to HTTPS
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name fabrikam.com;
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri?;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name fabrikam.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fabrikam.com/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/fabrikam.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you configure `NameVirtualHost` ?

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm not sure what that is. A separate configuration file?

Comment: Uh I see it's Apache 2.4, so it doesn't matter. Sorry for that. Umm... you are writing you are accessing `https://fabrikam.com` yet your config listens on port 80 (`http`, not s). Something is off there ;-) You need a config for an SSL vhost listening on :443.

Comment: Yeah I should have specified -- the NGINX instance is running TLS certificates, and accesses Varnish over TCP 6081. Varnish is configured to hit Apache 2.4 on HTTP (non-TLS) port 80.

Comment: @Marki I just added the output from `apachectl -S`

Comment: Is the HTTP host header using in name based virtual hosting being correctly forwarded through nginx and varnish?? When using SSL in the frontend you need to pass the host specified via SNI.

Comment: @Marki Good question -- I had a feeling it might be something related to the middle-tier services. How could I verify this? Some way to see the headers that Apache is seeing?

Comment: Yeah, wireshark. But since the original problem is that it doesn't but your config looms legit, probably means the problem is nginx or varnish. Please post nginx and varnish config.

Comment: @Marki Your comments got me on the right track. The Varnish configuration was pointing to Apache on TCP 8080 instead of TCP 80. This is why the rule wasn't matching.

Comment: I fixed the Apache VirtualHost configuration to match 8080, and it started working. However, I have a new problem with redirects.

Comment: I've created an answer. Feel free to accept. If there are further problems please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that Apache is hit on the correct instance/port and with the Host header correctly forwarded through the middle tiers.